# javascript printing array into paragraphs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a local html to display some text from txt file (also local).
I used this to read file into array and print it:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="inputfile">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById('inputfile')
.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var test=new FileReader();
    test.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById('output')
                .textContent=fl.result;
    }
    test.readAsText(this.files[0]);
})
</script>
```

However, I would like to print it from the array into paragraphs, line by line (first line goes into heading, second into paragraph, third into heading and so on...).
Is there a way to do it automaticaly from an array, or would I have to do it by hand for each one?
I am kinda green in javascript so I would rather refrain from using node etc.

Comment: You can loop through your array and define which index belongs to which section, such as 0 = header, 1 = paragraph, 2 = heading, > 2 = the rest, etc.

Comment: "first line goes into heading, second into paragraph, third into heading and so on..." Is it *always* going to be strictly alternating header, paragraph, header, paragraph?  If there might sometimes be two paragraphs for a given header you'll need something other than just array position to indicate that.

Comment: @Daniel It is always going to be like that. It's pretty much title and description

Comment: Could you share how your array value looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = ['Heading 1','Para1','Heading 2','Para2','Heading 3','Para3'];

const result = arr.map((val, i) => i%2===0 ? `<h2>${val}</h2>` : `<p>${val}</p>`).join('');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result ;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I am not sure what am I doing wrong, but it does break apart when wraping into header, just after odd or even part. For some reason "<h1>" and entire last line is treated as simple text, not a code

Comment: share error and code which breaks

Comment: @OnionOfDoom make sure you use `innerHTML`. It will be easy if you share content from file which breaks

Comment: Nevermind, it does actually work just like I wanted to, I jsut made a mistake while typing it in. So thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If the headers and paragraphs are always strictly alternating, you can check whether each array index is odd or even to decide whether to wrap it in header or paragraph tags.  One way:

```js
arr = ["header", "paragraph", "header", "paragraph", "header", "paragraph"]

joined = arr.map((el, i) => {
  return (i % 2 === 0) ? `<h1>${el}</h1>` : `<p>${el}</p>` ;
}).join('')

console.log(joined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your code:

```
function arrToPar(arr){ //For JS-Array --> HTML content
    var out = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        out += arr[i] + "<br>";
    }
    return(out);
}
```

Or...

```
function arrToString(arr,joiner = " "){ //For JS-Array --> JS-String
    var out = ""; //The parameter "joiner", by default, is a space
    //This means that you only need to specify "arr", but you can do
    //a second parameter. This function behaves like arr.join(joiner).
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        out += arr[i] + joiner;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second example is equivalent to `arr.join(" ")`, probably not necessary to reinvent that.  (But note that they asked for different output than you're producing).

Comment: 1st method worked for render array of strings convert in to single paragraph with my custom format. Thanks!